# dict get item from key

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to get a key-value item from a dictionary using a key instead of getting only the value.
I understand that I could do something like

```
foo = {"bar":"baz", "hello":"world"}
some_item = {"bar": foo.get("bar")}
```

But here I need to type out the key twice, which seems a bit redundant. Is there some direct way to get the key-value pair for the key `bar`? Something like

```
foo.get_item("bar")
>>> {"bar": "baz"}
```

Comment: `def pair(foo, bar): return (bar, foo[bar])`

Comment: Are you specifically trying to create a new dictionary with that key:val ?

Comment: Why do you want a pair ? It is likely that the first thing you will do with it is to process the key or the value in isolation...

Comment: @Marcel Wilson No, not particularly.

Comment: Mainly for parsing and passing kwargs @YvesDaoust

Comment: I see. Do you even need to store them in a dictionary as key/value pairs ?

Comment: `{k:v for k,v in foo.items() if k=='bar'}`

Comment: What's the problem with `{k: foo.get(k)}`? Using `k` twice is not redundant, it's explicit. Otherwise, if you want a dictionary "subset" you can always use a comprehension: `{k: foo[k] for k in ['bar']}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way or another, you'll need to bind `"bar"` to a variable.

```
>>> foo = {"bar":"baz", "hello":"world"}
>>> (lambda k="bar": {k: foo[k]})()
{'bar': 'baz'}
```

or:

```
>>> k = "bar"
>>> {k: foo[k]}
{'bar': 'baz'}
```

or:

```
>>> def item(d, k):
...     return {k: d[k]}
...
>>> item(foo, "bar")
{'bar': 'baz'}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to extend `dict` to create your own methods. It could be useful if you're the one creating the initial dictionary in the first place.

```py
class MyDict(dict):
    def fetch(self, key):
        return {key:self.get(key)}
```

The downside is you would need to recast regular dictionaries (assuming you didn't create the initial)

```py
new_foo = MyDict(foo)
some_item = new_foo.fetch("bar")
```

But in this case it would probably be easier just to use a lambda (see [Samwise's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71472611/2532408))

Answer (score -1):

you can get the key value pair for key 'bar' by doing something like ->

```
foo = {"bar":"baz", "hello":"world"}
some_item = {k:v for k,v in foo.items() if k=='bar'}
```

Comment: This solution requires me to iterate over the entire dict though, which isn't really efficient.